# How to improve the speed of splitting a list?

Tags: python, performance, list, pandas

I just want to improve the speed of splitting a list.Now I have a way to split the list, but the speed is not as fast as I expected.

```
def split_list(lines):
        return [x for xs in lines for x in xs.split('-')]

import time

lst= []
for i in range(1000000):
    lst.append('320000-320000')

start=time.clock()
lst_new=split_list(lst)
end=time.clock()
print('time\n',str(end-start))
```

For example,`Input`:

```
lst
 ['320000-320000', '320000-320000']
```

`Output`:

```
lst_new
 ['320000', '320000', '320000', '320000']
```

I'm not satisfied with the speed of spliting,as my data contains many lists.

But now I don't know whether there's a more effective way to do it.

---

According to advice,I try to describe my whole question more specifically.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'line':["320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000",
                            "380000-320000",
                            "380000-320000,380000-310000",
                            "370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000",
                            "320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000",
                            "380000-320000",
                            "380000-320000,380000-310000",
                            "370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000",
                            "320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000",
                            "380000-320000",
                            "380000-320000,380000-310000",
                            "370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000"], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],})

def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

def split_list(lines):
    return [x for xs in lines for x in xs.split('-')]

df['line']=df['line'].str.split(',')
col_ix=df['line'].index.values
df['line_start'] = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)
df['line_destination'] = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)

import time 
start=time.clock()

for ix in col_ix:
    col=df['line'][ix]
    col_split=split_list(col)
    even_col_split=col_split[0:][::2]
    even_col_split_most=most_common(even_col_split)
    df['line_start'][ix]=even_col_split_most

    odd_col_split=col_split[1:][::2]

    odd_col_split_most=most_common(odd_col_split)
    df['line_destination'][ix]=odd_col_split_most

end=time.clock()
print('time\n',str(end-start))

del df['line']
print('df\n',df)
```

`Input`:

```
df
 id                                         line
0    1  320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000
1    2                                380000-320000
2    3                  380000-320000,380000-310000
3    4    370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000
4    5  320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000
5    6                                380000-320000
6    7                  380000-320000,380000-310000
7    8    370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000
8    9  320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000
9   10                                380000-320000
10  11                  380000-320000,380000-310000
11  12    370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000
```

`Output`:

```
df
 id  line_start  line_destination
0    1     320000    320000
1    2     380000    320000
2    3     380000    320000
3    4     370000    320000
4    5     320000    320000
5    6     380000    320000
6    7     380000    320000
7    8     370000    320000
8    9     320000    320000
9   10     380000    320000
10  11     380000    320000
11  12     370000    320000
```

You can regard the number of `line`(eg.`320000-32000` represent the starting point and destination of the route).

`Expected`:
Make the code run faster.(I can't bear the speed of the code)

Comment: First use `timeit` to time code snippets. Second, can you give more context about your actual problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa .  As it stands, you're looking to flatten a list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'-'.join(lst).split('-')
```

seems quite a bit faster:

```
>>> timeit("'-'.join(lst).split('-')", globals=globals(), number=10)
1.0838123590219766
>>> timeit("[x for xs in lst for x in xs.split('-')]", globals=globals(), number=10)
3.1370303670410067
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do with your list, using a genertor can be slightly faster.

If you need to keep the output stored, then the list solution is faster.

If all you need to is to iterate over the *words* once, you can get rid of some overhead by using a generator.

```
def split_list_gen(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield from line.split('-')
```

### Benchmark

```
import time

lst = ['32000-32000'] * 10000000

start = time.clock()
for x in split_list(lst):
    pass
end = time.clock()
print('list time:', str(end - start))

start = time.clock()
for y in split_list_gen(lst):
    pass
end = time.clock()
print('generator time:', str(end - start))
```

### Output

The generator solution is consistently about 10% faster.

```
list time: 0.4568295369982612
generator time: 0.4020671741918084
```

Comment: Upvoted to cancel it out... This seems like the answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing more of the work below the Python level seems to provide a small speedup:

```
In [7]: %timeit x = split_list(lst)
407 ms ± 876 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [8]: %timeit x = list(chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller("split", "-"), lst
   ...: )))
374 ms ± 2.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`methodcaller` creates a function that calls the function for you:

```
methodcaller("split", "-")(x) == x.split("-")
```

`chain.from_iterable` creates a single iterator consisting of the elements from a group of iterables:

```
list(chain.from_iterable([[1,2], [3,4]])) == [1,2,3,4]
```

`map`ping the function returned by `methodcaller` on to your list of strings produces an iterable of lists suitable for flattening by `from_iterable`. The benefit of this more functional approach is that the functions involved are all implemented in C and can work with the data *in* the Python objects, rather than Python byte code that works *on* the Python objects.